# Capture user info in Sentry

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, sentry

I have just recently started using Sentry on my Laravel 5.1 application.

I see in there docs, and getting started stuff, a reference to [capturing user information](https://docs.sentry.io/hosted/learn/context/?_ga=1.219964441.1220115692.1472094716#capturing-the-user).

The example they give of passing this in, looks like this:

```
Raven.setUserContext({
    email: 'foo@example.com'
});
```

Having followed their [setup instructions for Laravel](https://docs.sentry.io/hosted/clients/php/integrations/laravel/?_ga=1.14131511.1220115692.1472094716), I see no reference for where this could go or any reference in the documentation for how to set this up in a config file or anything for Laravel.

Any ideas on how I could set this up to send user information? Users will always be logged in when using my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realise this question is three months old, so apologies if you’ve already found the answer.

I had the same requirements (log user as part of exceptions in Sentry) so did a little digging myself.

`Raven.setUserContext()` seems to be a function specific to the JavaScript SDK. The PHP SDK has a `set_user_data($id, $email, $data)` method on the Raven client that you can use somewhere in your application (most likely in your exception handler before you actually send the exception to Sentry).

Something like this should work:

```php
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    // Will only enter if statement if request has a user
    if ($user = request()->user()) {
        app('sentry')->set_user_data($user->getAuthIdentifier(), $user->email);
    }

    app('sentry')->captureException($e);

    return parent::report($e);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good way of doing it. I resorted to using an outdated package and modifying it slightly as this was the only solution I could find. I will give this a go, though - thanks!

Comment: How to do this for react.js-redux ?

Comment: @Qui-GonJinn I don’t know. This question is about Laravel.